# How to pass a 'tap' to UIButton that is underneath UIView with UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIButton underneath a (transparent) UIView. The UIView above has a UISwipeGestureRecognizer added to it, and that is its only purpose - to detect certain swipe gestures. I want all other touches to be ignored by that UIView, and passed to other views (such as my UIButton underneath). Currently, the UIView above seems to be detecting the tap (for example), doing nothing (as it should be), and not letting the UIButton underneath get a chance to respond.

I would prefer not to implement my own swipe recognizer, if possible. Any solutions / advice? I basically just want to know how to tell a UIView to pay attention to only a certain type of added gesture recognizer, and ignore (and thus let through to views behind) all other touches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must have just been in a funk yesterday - I woke up with a simple solution today. Add the UISwipeGesture to a view which is a superview to both the UIView and the UIButton. Then, when processing those swipes, figure out where the swipe originated, and whether that point is in the frame of where I used to have the UIView. (As I mentioned, the only reason for the existence of the UIView was to define a target area for these swipe gestures.)

Answer (score 14):

Have you set:

```
mySwipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

to allow the touches to be sent to the view hierarchy as well as the gesture?

Additionally, ensure that the view on top is:

```
theTransparentView.opaque = NO;
theTransparentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

I've had pretty good success attaching gestures to the parent view without needing to create a transparent subview on top for the gesture. Are you sure you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put your button on top of the view and add gesture recognisers to that button too?

In the end, your UIButton inherits form UIView via UIControl. Therefore there is practically nothing that you could do with a view but not with a button.

Comment: No, I can't put the UIButton above the UIView, for unrelated reasons - and I don't think it would be smart to do so anyway to try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by not using a button, but rather a UITapGestureRecognizer. My pan gesture recognizer was added to the background view, and the tap gesture was added to a view above it.